# Angular DatePicker display to the current year

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I tried to configure my datepicker. I would like that the last year is my current year. It works for a simple date but not if it's a daterange.
Have you an idea, how to configure the daterange to have same beahaviour that simple date ?

Date (with [max] it works)

```
<input type="hidden" [matDatepicker]="picker" [max]="today" #pickerInputOne (dateChange)="dateInputOne.value = getDate(filter.id, pickerInputOne.value)" >
```

[image: Date]

DateRange (with [max], not works like I want, not same behaviour):

```
<input type="hidden" [satDatepicker]="satPicker" [max]="today"  #pickerInputTwo (dateChange)="dateInput.value = getDateRange(filter.id,  pickerInputTwo.value)" >
```

[image: DateRange]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You seam to be using two different datepickers. The [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) in your first example and [Saturn Datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saturn-datepicker) in your second example. So obviously they may behave differently. What is your goal? Do you want the `Saturn Datepicker` to behave like the `Angular Material Datepicker`?

Comment: @fridoo you are it's very confusing.

Comment: I'm using matDatepicker to pick a date, and i'm using Saturn Datepicker to pick a range of date. I would like the behaviour of material for saturn.

Comment: This feature of the `Angular Material Datepicker` was added in version 8.0.2. See https://github.com/angular/components/releases/tag/8.0.2 and https://github.com/angular/components/commit/400a95b . I guess `Saturn Datepicker` is based on an older version of the `Angular Material Datepicker` and hasn't incorporated these changes yet. You should file an issue in the [Saturn Repo](https://github.com/SaturnTeam/saturn-datepicker) and request an update or merge the current version of `Angular Material Datepicker` into `Saturn Datepicker` yourself.

Comment: The date range feature will be added to the `Angular Material Datepicker` sometime. You can follow https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4763 . I guess the easiest way would be to wait until then, using the `Saturn Datepicker` in the mean time and just dealing with a not perfectly looking UI for a couple of month.

Comment: Yes, I think waiting for the feature